# Difference between almost the same directory commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is there any difference between these (almost the same) directory commands?

```
1. cd
2. cd ~
3. cd ~/
```

I tried it in my shell, and they all lead to the home directory. Is there any possible scenario where they are different?

Answer (score 9):

POSIX defines that...

1. ...if `cd` was not given any arguments, it will use the value of `$HOME` if the variable is set, and do nothing otherwise (although it *also* says that results are unspecified). — [`cd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html)
2. ...if an argument is `~` or begins with `~/`, the tilde will be expanded to the value of `$HOME` if the variable is set; the results are unspecified otherwise. — [`tilde expansion`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01)

So **if `$HOME` is set, then all three commands are equivalent.** (Extra slashes after directory names are meaningless.)

---

However, if `$HOME` is *not* set, then the results of both `~`-expansion and `cd` are **unspecified**:

- In *bash*, AT&T *ksh*, and Heirloom *sh*, plain `cd` will fail with "no home directory".
- In *csh*, *zsh*, *dash*, and MirBSD *mksh*, plain `cd` will do nothing.
- In *tcsh*, plain `cd` will look up the home directory using `getpwuid()`.

As for the `~` expansion...

- *bash* and *tcsh* will expand `~` to the home directory from `getpwnam()`.
- AT&T *ksh* will expand `~` to your username (?!).
- In *csh* and *zsh*, `~` will expand to an empty string. (`cd ~` will therefore do nothing, like plain `cd`, in those shells.)
- In *dash* and MirBSD *mksh*, the `~` will remain a literal `~`. (Using `cd ~` will try to change to a directory named such.)
- Heirloom *sh* never expands `~` even if `$HOME` is set – it probably predates the convention.

Out of these, only *csh* and *zsh* stick to the POSIX definition of expanding `~` to the value of `$HOME` even if it is empty.

(The *fish* shell always sets `$HOME` from `getpwnam()` on startup if the variable empty, and refuses to modify it afterwards.)

Comment: Do you know this by heart or did you really go the extra mile?

Comment: I had the shells already installed, so...

Comment: Your remark about AT&T's ksh expanding to the username reminded me of a neat trick in bash, dash and probably others: `cd ~<username>` will take you to `<username>`'s home.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can imagine a scenario where 1 is different to 2 and 3. Try defining the following function in bash:

```
cd () { if (($#)) ; then builtin cd "$1" ; else cd / ; fi ; }
```

1. will take you to `/`, while 2. and 3. will take you home.

Comment: perfect cause i wanna go home :(